# Ubuntu: create a new partition on /dev/sdb1 (which still has 1.5tb of free space) and mount it on /tmp/

Tags: linux, caffe, ubuntu-16.04, partition

As you can see /dev/sda is mounted to /. Thats where /tmp/ is located as shown image. Since It is running out of space on my / partition,I can't install caffe, and there is error: No space left on device.
Now I want to create a new partition on /dev/sdb1 (which still has 1.5tb of free space) and mount it on /tmp/.

[image]

Could you guys tell me how to create a new partition for solving this issue by linux command.
thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the following command

To unmont the existing volume give the following

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Note:- Make sure no process is using the particular directory

Then again mount it to /tmp

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp
```

or

```
cd /dev/ && sudo mount sdb1 /tmp
```

Comment: thanks, but : the umount: /data: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

Comment: just give 'lsof /data' it will list all the process which are using /data along with its PID's . Then kill all the process using the command 'sudo kill -9 <PID>